# How to make added element by jQuery knows recent functions

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, call

I have an html table each row (tr) have a value (exp: 200$) and a delete button, how to make
each added row knows recent functions without recall them every time

```
$(function () {
    $('.add-prod').on("click", function (e) {
        $('#products_tbody').append('<tr >...</tr>');
        afterAddProd();
        change1();
        change2();
    });
    function afterAddProd() {
        ...
    };

    function change1() {
            ...
    }
    function change2() {
        ...
    }
}
```

cause when i delete a row the total of values will decrease three times for example

Comment: Little unclear, but I would recommend you completely *recalculate* from *all* rows each time rather than keep a running total in a variable; in-case something goes wrong with that total.

Comment: *delete a row the total of values will decrease three times* - then there's a problem with your delete function.  Maybe you call `$(".delete-prod").on("click"` multiple times so you get multiple delete events.

Comment: because each time i add a row i had to recall the delete function or it won't work, that's the problem

Comment: Right, so it's the code that adds the delete event handler.  When you do `$(".delete-prod").click` it adds another event to *all* the delete buttons - so 3 delete buttons = 3 delete actions (on the first at least).  Either add the delete event to just the one that was just added or use event delegation.  .appendTo can help with this eg `$("<tr>..</tr>").appendTo("#tbody").find(".delete_button").click(...` will apply the click event to just the .delete_button on the just-added row.  Or use `$(document).on("click", ".delete_button"...` just *once* outside the add-prod code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of event delegation. You can set up a single delete function using jQuery's `container.on(event, selector...` that will work for any dynamically created button inside of a container. Here's an example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.added').on('click', 'button.del', function() {
    $(this).closest('.item').remove();
    tally()
  })

  $('button.add').click(function() {
    let n = $('.tpl').clone().removeAttr('hidden').removeClass('tpl').addClass('item');
    n.find('input.qty').val(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
    n.appendTo($('.added'))
    tally()

  })


  function tally() {
    let ttl = 0;
    $('.added input.qty').each(function() {
      ttl += +$(this).val()
    })
    $('.ttl').html(ttl)
  }


})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='add'>add</button>
<div class='added'>

</div>

<strong> total: <span class='ttl'></span></strong>

<div class='tpl' hidden>
  This is the new data <input type='number' class='qty' /> <button class='del'>delete</button>

</div>
```